# RSA encryption post request JAVA

Tags: java, post, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have to do an Integration with a platform. The platform provided me a Public Key to encrypt the data to call their API. While sending the request I need to consider following:

1. The request is HTTPS/POST request.
2. The request must be like :

```
{ 
    Base64Encode(
        RSA_Encrypt( 
            { "a" : "111111", "b" : "12234", "c" : "2342342", "d" : "612413726581" }
        )
    )
}
```

I am putting the parameters like below:

```java
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("a", "112227");
parameters.put("b", "5411");
parameters.put("c", "12345678");
parameters.put("d", "123456");
```

Encrypting like below:

```java
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("{");
for (String parameterName : parameters.keySet()) { 
    sb.append("\""+parameterName+"\"").append(':').append("\""+parameters.get(parameterName)+"\"").append(',');
}

String s=sb.toString();
s=s.replaceAll(",\\Z", "");
s=s+"}";

byte[] cleartext = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
String path="Path to certificate file\\rsa_apikey.cer";

FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
CertificateFactory f;
PublicKey pk;
try {
    f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
    pk = certificate.getPublicKey();

} catch (CertificateException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");   
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);  
byte[] ciphertext=cipher.doFinal(cleartext);
String securePayload = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext);
```

After that, I am sending the POST request. The request is still showing 400 bad request error. I don't know whether I am doing it properly.

Questiong 1) Please suggest what is the best way to do it?

Question 2) I am getting Base64 String "securePayload" different everytime. Can it be the reason for bad request?

Comment: In order to determine what went wrong we'd need to know the specifications, and you haven't provided that. Normally, RSA is not used to directly encrypt data. Instead, AES encrypts the data and RSA encrypts the AES key. Well, actually, normally HTTPS is the only layer used for security, adding another layer like ad-hoc RSA doesn't really do much except add complexity and confusion. Finally, use a purpose-built JSON serializer instead of trying to write one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My padding was wrong and because of that I was getting error. I updated to PKCS1 and now it is working fine. Thanks.

```
PublicKey publicKey=readPublicKey(path);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");   
        cipher.init(Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);  
        byte[] ciphertext=cipher.doFinal(cleartext);
```